# Access HTC wm6.5 camera using .NET

Tags: c#, camera, computer-vision, windows-mobile-6.5

Well i have a htc diamond 2 which run on wm6.5, I would like to access the built in camera to capture image.
I am not building wm app, i want to build a c#(or any other .NET) winform app that run on windows 7 platform.
Is that possible?
I found some articles about directshow.net,wia,windowsmobile camera capture dialog etc.But i really have no idea on how to start it.
So my question is:

1. How do i establish a connection to my phone(i have to initiate a connection between my pc and phone's camera first right?),do i need to download any windows mobile sdk?
2. To control the camera, do i need any driver installed?
3. Do i use htc camera api/sdk(which i can't find) or windows mobile api/sdk to control the camera?

Comment: I never done any programming for windows mobile platform, what i want is to be able to control the camera in my htc diamond 2 which run on wm6.5, is it possible?
And do i need to download any driver or program first so that i can connect my phone to my pc. I connect them using usb, nothing happen.
Just to clarify again, i just want to make a desktop winform app, not a windows mobile app.

Comment: Ah... You didn't clarify that. I believe there are ways to interact with phone through ActiveSync. See myMobiler for example. But it requires application on device and on windows which will comunicate one which other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For HTC devices DirectShow cannot be used. The problem is that HTC provides only basic DirectShow API, and you will be able only use very small resolution from camera 320x240. HTC doen't provide any SDK. But I found very useful components for Windows Mobile Direct Show on this page. They are paid but quite good. I think it is worth to check. I'm using Player Control for DirectShow video playing. And there HCTCamera component (Some raw version I think still free) which I didn't check but you can:

[HTCCamera Control](http://alexmogurenko.com/blog/uncategorized/htccamera-v10/)

Comment: hey thx for the help, will try the dll later.
Btw did u try any windows mobile sdk to control it before?
There must be a way to control all wm6.5 phone hardware to do some simple actions right(in my case just captue image with low resolution)?

Comment: I'm programing a lot on WM, Maily 6.0, but a lot. SDK will allow you to launch bilt inn camera app. Not to nativelly work with camery in your application

Comment: may i know what is the meaning of launch built in camera app?
once the app launched, can i use the sdk to control the built in camera app function? 
because for my case, i just need to use the camera to capture image and save it in storage,then i will retrieve it for further image processing.I don't really need any display to show the preview, i just need a function to fire the camera and retrieve the shooted picture(i can accept any format).

Comment: Sorry, i never played with built in campera bacue withtou subclassing you cannot automate it. If the basic resolution is enough for you will have to go DirectShow C++ + .NET runtime. There is no pure .NET way to do that. And there are examples on MSDN how to create such DirectShow wrapper in C++. Or you can use control I mentioned in answer.

Comment: the htccameracontrol?i can't reference the cameranative dll,not sure what is the problem.
By using this control or other api, i wonder how they communicate with the phone? i have to download the mobile device centre first right?

Comment: I just try the directshow yesterday, i can detect the usb webcam and built in webcam in my laptop and able to take photo.However phone camera is not detected, so i do need to establish a connection between the phone and my laptop right(by using windows mobile driver or ..,sorry i never learn to use windows phone before)?

Comment: You cannot use phone as camera directly. Like I was written: this is not easy task. I'm helping only with wm part. All other communication you need to handle by yourself. The idea is use HTC camera to take picture on some running program on device. Then you need to use some communication to send data to your windows app.

Comment: Ok i got it, will try out my first window mobile program to control the camera,then just take out the picture from my phone since file access between pc and wm phone seem to be easier to handle.